# How to negate a lookbehind regex?

Tags: r, regex

Yet another post on negative lookbehind in regex in R but I can't find what I'm doing wrong here.

I have these strings:

```r
test <- c("a %in% c('b', 'e')" , "case_when(a %in% c('b', 'e'))", "hello")
```

I want to detect which strings contain a `%in%` without being preceded by a `case_when(`. I can find which ones contain a `case_when(` and then a `%in%` with this regex:

```r
grepl("(?=.*case\\_when\\()(.*%in%)", test, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So I just need to negate this lookbehind and I thought replacing `=` by `<!` was enough but apparently not:

```r
grepl("(?<!case\\_when\\()(.*%in%)", test, perl = TRUE)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The expected output is `TRUE FALSE FALSE`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy. It matches everything, *including* `case_when`. That said, `.*%in%` matches `case_when(a %in%`, and since this phrase is not preceded by another `case_when(`, it is counted as a match.

```
case_when(a %in% c('b', 'e'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^
    '.*'
```

You can replace `.` with `[^(]` so as not to match opening brackets, and use the [`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912) idiom to exclude what you don't want.

```r
case_when\(      # Match 'case_when('
[^(]*%in%        # followed by 0+ non-opening-bracket character and '%in'.
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)   # then skip and forfeit everything we just matched
|                # before matching
[^(]*%in%        # every other instance of `[^(]*%in%`.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CZuQ5o/1).

Try it:

```r
test <- c("a %in% c('b', 'e')", "case_when(a %in% c('b', 'e'))", "hello")
grepl("case_when\\([^\\(]*%in%(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^\\(]*%in%", test, perl = TRUE)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Do note that parsing (presumably) R, a non-regular language, with regex is most likely not a good choice.

Comment: Thanks, I added a small code snippet with the final R code

Answer (score 1):

Does not (`?!` -- negative lookahead) start (`^`) with `"case_when"` and contains `"%in%"`:

```r
grepl("^(?!case_when).*%in%.*", test, perl = T)
```

Or you could break it into two matches (do not detect `"case_when"` *and* detect `"%in%"`):

```r
!grepl("case_when", test, fixed = T) & grepl("%in%", test, fixed = T)
```

Comment: Your regex cannot deal with this: `"mutate(case_when(a %in% c('b', 'e')))"` The expected output is FALSE.